# How to delete a polygon on map

Tags: ios, dictionary, polygon

I implemented a map using apple's native f/w and I have implemented the functionality to add some polygons over the map. Now, I want to have a "close" button at the edge of the each polygon and when I click on that button, i need to delete the polygon (one polygon at a time). I have tried creating a button over the polygon edge, but I was unable to make an action on clicking the button. I have tried with annotations as well. In this case, I am unable create a close button over all the polygons; I could able to have the close button (annotation) only on the last polygon which was created but when I click on the button, the polygon which was created first only was getting deleted.
Kindly suggest me a solution to have a close button on each polygon, and to delete a polygon(one by one) on clicking the button.